# Get HTML span elements to gridview vb net

Tags: html, vb.net

What I'm trying to do is get all att and elements by tag name into DataGridView1.
The code seems ok, but when I run the app it is not doing anything. It looks like it is doing some background work, but nothing is going to DataGridView.

```
Public Class GetElements
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument
    Dim he As HtmlElement

    Private Sub btnGetGetElements_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetElements.Click
        WB.Navigate("http://website.com/")
        WB.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub WB_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WB.DocumentCompleted
        doc = WB.Document

        If Not doc Is Nothing Then
            he = doc.GetElementById("listable")


            If Not he Is Nothing Then

                For Each item As HtmlElement In he.Children

                    If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                        If item.Name = "thead" Then
                            For Each head As HtmlElement In item.Children
                                If head.Name = "tr" Then
                                    For Each trhead As HtmlElement In head.Children
                                        If trhead.Name = "th" Then
                                            Dim colname As String = trhead.InnerText
                                            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colname.Replace(" ", "_"), colname)
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If



                    Dim data As String()
                    Dim idxr As Integer = 0

                    If item.InnerText = "tbody" Then
                        For Each tr As HtmlElement In item.Children
                            If tr.InnerHtml.ToLower().Contains("tr") Then
                                For Each td As HtmlElement In tr.Children
                                    If td.InnerHtml.ToLower().Contains("td") Then
                                        data(idxr) = td.InnerText
                                        idxr += 1
                                    End If
                                Next

                                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(data)
                                idxr = 0

                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                Next
            End If


        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```